# Display <div> relative to <textarea>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a box (a single absolutely positioned `<div>`). I also have a series of `<textarea>` and `<input type="text">` form controls. When I focus on any `<textarea>` I want to display the box to the left on the focused item (covering whatever lies beneath), possibly with a fancy faceIn() animation:

```
+-----------+---------------------------
| div       | textarea                 |
|           |                          |
|           |                          |
+-----------+                          |
            |                          |
            |                          |
            |                          |
            +--------------------------+
```

I *think* I can use jQuery or jQuery UI Position to position the element for me (after all, calendars displayed by jQuery UI Datepicker behaviour are quite similar to what I want for my box) but I can't make my way through docs. First of all, both libraries have different items with the same name:

- jQuery: [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/)
- jQuery UI: [.position()](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

... and both have the same kind of limitation:

- *jQuery does not support getting the position coordinates of hidden elements*
- *jQuery UI does not support positioning hidden elements.*

My code so far looks like this:

```css
#box{
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```js
var $box = $('<div id="box"></div>').hide().appendTo("#main-form");
$("#main-form").on("focus", ":text, textarea", function(){
    $text = $(this);
    $box.show("slow").position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left top",
        of: $text
    });
});
```

When I focus a textarea, `$box` shows up but it doesn't move from the left top corner of the window.

What am I missing?

---

**Edit:** With your advice, I quickly made it work (an animation-less version) in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VUnd/) but not in my app. Further debugging revealed I had forgotten to include the `Position` component in my jQuery UI custom download! It wasn't throwing an error because of the method with the same name in jQuery. Apparently, when you have both enabled, you get one or another depending on the *arguments*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the elements visibility to hidden instead of setting their display to none.

jQuery does not consider `visibility: hidden` to be a "hidden element".

Edit:

Also, I'm not sure this is correct.

```
$box.show("slow").position({
```

Your method `position()` is occurring *before* the animation is complete methinks. Try the following instead using the callback function.

```
$box.show("slow", function() {
    $box.position();
});
```

Comment: Great tip. `.css({visibility: "hidden"})` was all I needed to position the element before showing it, so I could use an animation.

Comment: Sadly, I can only accept one answer. I've chosen this because the `visibility` and animation callback tips can probably help others, but my main issue was that I wasn't even loading jQuery UI Position <:-)

Answer (score 1):

Position it after the show animation has ended, like this:

```
$box.show("slow", function() {
     $text = $(this);
     $(this).position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left top",
        of: $text
     });
});
```

Comment: Dammit... Works great in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VUnd/) but not in my app :(

Comment: Make sure you have a good installation of jquery-ui 1.8, otherwise you are using the basic jquery .position()

Comment: Dammit dammit... That was it!

Answer (score 1):

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2GHM/), and it works fine for me in FF/Chrome.  However, I would guess any issue you are having has to do with the position being attempted before the first step of `show()`, when the `#box` is still hidden.

A simple fix would be to `show().position().hide().show("slow")`.  This guarantees the `#box` will be visible when the position occurs, but because it happens quickly, you will never see it before it is hidden again.  Then you can take your time showing the `#box`:

```
$("#main-form").on("focus", ":text, textarea", function(){
    $text = $(this);
    $box.show().position({
        my: "right top",
        at: "left top",
        of: $text
    }).hide().show("slow");
});
```

It also has the added "feature" of having the `show` animation occur on each new focus event.

http://jsfiddle.net/C2GHM/1/